# How to optimize a case expression in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a long case expression that i need to optimize:

```
update tf
   SET class
   case
        WHEN tf.column = 'a' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl1  where code = 1)
        WHEN tf.column = 'b' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl1  where code = 2)
        WHEN tf.column = 'c' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl1  where code = 3)
        WHEN tf.column = 'd' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl1  where code = 80)

   end
   SET name
   case
        WHEN tf.column2 = 'ryan' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl2  where code = 12)
        WHEN tf.column2 = 'david' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl2  where code = 22)
        WHEN tf.column2 = 'tan' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl2  where code = 32)
        WHEN tf.column2 = 'drake' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl2  where code = 802)

   end
   SET department
   case
        WHEN tf.column3 like 'd.d%' then 'Director D'
        WHEN tf.column3 like '%AC'  then  'Accounting'

   end

FROM trans_tbl tf WHERE flag is null
```

I'm cleaning up the trans_tbl table. I need to replace abbreviations with actual names and fix the data in that table.
is there another way or a better way to do this?

Comment: IMHO, if that table is not large you don't need an optimization. Otherwise you could create a temp table or table variable that has both columns from those tables (tf.[column], code) as a "bridge" table and join using it.

Comment: What is slow in that query?

Answer (score 0):

Note my sample data, solution and comments:

```
-- 1. CREATE TABLES FOR SAMPLE DATA
DECLARE @transform_tbl TABLE
(
  col1  CHAR(1),
  col2  VARCHAR(20),
  class VARCHAR(100),
  [name] VARCHAR(100),
  flag  BIT,
  INDEX uq_flag CLUSTERED (flag) -- A Unique nonclustered, filtered index would be best
)
DECLARE @lookup1 TABLE (x INT, xx INT, INDEX idx_lu1 CLUSTERED(x)); -- you want an index on x
DECLARE @lookup2 TABLE (x INT, xx VARCHAR(100), INDEX idx_lu2 CLUSTERED(x)); -- you want an index on x

-- 2. POPULATE TABLES WITH SAMPLE DATA
INSERT  @lookup1 VALUES (1,111),(2,222),(3,333),(80,8080);
INSERT  @lookup2 VALUES (12,'sally'),(22,'sue'),(32,'betty'),(802,'lulu');
INSERT @transform_tbl(col1,col2,class)
  VALUES('a','ryan','xxx'),('b','david','xxx'),('c','tan','xxx'),('d','drake','xxx');
INSERT @transform_tbl(col1,col2,class,flag)
  VALUES('x','','xxx',1),('x','','xxx',0),('x','','xxx',1),('x','','xxx',1);

-- 3. SELECT Statement to understand the update
SELECT tf.col1, tf.col2, tf.[name], Class = lu1.XX, [Name] = lu2.XX
FROM @transform_tbl AS tf
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE
    WHEN tf.col1 = 'a' THEN 1
    WHEN tf.col1 = 'b' THEN 2
    WHEN tf.col1 = 'c' THEN 3
    WHEN tf.col1 = 'd' THEN 80 END)) AS f(Class)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE
    WHEN tf.col2 = 'ryan'  THEN 12
    WHEN tf.col2 = 'david' THEN 22
    WHEN tf.col2 = 'tan'   THEN 32
    WHEN tf.col2 = 'drake' THEN 802 END)) AS f2([Name])
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) lu.xx from @lookup1 AS lu where x = f.Class)   AS lu1(XX)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) lu.xx from @lookup2 AS lu where x = f2.[Name]) AS lu2(XX)
WHERE tf.flag IS NULL;

-- 4. Change the SELECT to an UPDATE
;
-- SELECT tf.col1, tf.col2, tf.[name], Class = lu1.XX, [Name] = lu2.XX
UPDATE tf SET Class = lu1.XX, [Name] = lu2.XX
FROM @transform_tbl AS tf
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE
    WHEN tf.col1 = 'a' THEN 1
    WHEN tf.col1 = 'b' THEN 2
    WHEN tf.col1 = 'c' THEN 3
    WHEN tf.col1 = 'd' THEN 80 END)) AS f(Class)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE
    WHEN tf.col2 = 'ryan'  THEN 12
    WHEN tf.col2 = 'david' THEN 22
    WHEN tf.col2 = 'tan'   THEN 32
    WHEN tf.col2 = 'drake' THEN 802 END)) AS f2([Name])
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) lu.xx from @lookup1 AS lu where x = f.Class)   AS lu1(XX)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) lu.xx from @lookup2 AS lu where x = f2.[Name]) AS lu2(XX)
WHERE tf.flag IS NULL

-- 5. Review Results
SELECT tf.col1, tf.[name], tf.class
FROM   @transform_tbl AS tf
WHERE tf.flag IS NULL;
```

**Results (Before):**

```
col1 col2                 name   Class   Name
---- -------------------- ------ ------- ---------
a    ryan                 NULL   111     sally
b    david                NULL   222     sue
c    tan                  NULL   333     betty
d    drake                NULL   8080    lulu
```

**Results (After):**

```
col1 name    class
---- ------- --------
a    sally   111
b    sue     222
c    betty   333
d    lulu    8080
```

This code is notably cleaner and easier to maintain provided you understand how [APPLY](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-and-using-apply-part-1) works.

Note the indexes I used. The resulting execution plan will be all seeks and nested loop joins which is the best you can get for a query like this (using standard, conventional methods.)

Answer (score -1):

For every record an entire select it's launch (so if in the update table you have 1000 record you will do other 1000 select). An easy way to optimize this query it's save the select into variable.

```
declare @a varchar(20), -- I don't know the type..
        @b varchar(20), ..

        @ryan varchar(20), ..



set  @a = select top 1 from lookup_tbl1  where code = 1
set  @b = select top 1 from lookup_tbl1  where code = 1

...

update tf
   SET class
   case
        WHEN tf.column = 'a' THEN @a
        WHEN tf.column = 'b' THEN @b
        WHEN tf.column = 'c' THEN @c
        WHEN tf.column = 'd' THEN @d

   end
   SET name
   case
        WHEN tf.column2 = 'ryan' THEN @ryan
        WHEN tf.column2 = 'david' THEN @david
        WHEN tf.column2 = 'tan' THEN @tan
        WHEN tf.column2 = 'drake' THEN @drake

   end
   SET department
   case
        WHEN tf.column3 like 'd.d%' then 'Director D'
        WHEN tf.column3 like '%AC'  then  'Accounting'

   end

FROM transform_tbl tf WHERE flag is null
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Are you sure that SQL engine doesn't optimize 1000 selects away, doing internally only one?